# Student in Italy (Valid D-Visa 1 Year) Travel Outside Italy While Awaiting First Permesso di Soggiorno

Tags: international-travel, schengen-visas, student-visas, permesso-di-soggiorno

I'm an international student (Indian Passport) and I've just started my first year of education here in Milan.  My study visa (D) is valid for a year, I've gotten my fiscale code and the receipt for my permesso di soggiorno.  I've been told appointments aren't available for 4-5 months.

With my visa, passport, and the application receipt, am I legally allowed to travel outside of Italy to other Schengen and non-Schengen countries?  My brother is getting married in a few months and I can't seem to find the right advice for first time students in Italy.

All the guidelines seem to be for renewals, expired permesso di soggiorno.